# Derivation of t2g eg splitting in octahedral field

Tags: crystal-field-theory

I am trying to make the derivation of the *d* orbitals splitting under an octahedral field but I am kind of at a loss and don't know of any literature that can provide a more introductory level of this subject (if you know of any, please let me know).

I am trying to follow the book "Magnetic Oxides" by Gerald F. Dionne but I understand half of what it says in regards to this.

I know that we want to use the crystal field as a perturbation to the hamiltonian of the center ion, and for that you need to diagonalize the matrix (picture from [here](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Crystal_field_theory))
[image]

And that's it, that's where my understanding ends. The subscripts of this matrix is the quantum number *m* and the regular *d* suborbitals are almost all a linear combination of spherical harmonics with different *m*. So how do I diagonalize it?

The book doesn't do an explicit matrix handling and it basically just tells you from the start what the *eg* and *t2g* orbital are comprised of, I am assuming the notation means something I am unaware of,  and that they have different perturbation energies. No explicit equation that makes you understand that is shown.

I am sorry if it all seems confusing, I am confused. I know the how to derive the octahedral field (in cartesians and spherical harmonics) and how each *d* suborbital is written in spherical harmonics. But I don't know how to obtain the different energy splitting due to the perturbation of the octahedral field, any guidance/book or help is appreciated. Thanks!

PD: I am not a chemist, that's why I don't know of any books where I could read about this subject and why I am probably not following that well the book I was given.

---

Edit:

Because of all the recommendations, I have been able to understand more clearly the procedure while looking at it from a matrix perspective rather than a group theory one (completely at a loss there).

My question is that I am not getting what I should be when obtaining the element of the matrix
[image]

When trying to obtain those numbers in Mathematica I obtain values that don't make sense. I defined the *d* wave function like
[image]

Here you can see one matrix entry as an example
[image]

When doing the same as above for the four that appear in the image, I get that the factors before the *Dq* need to be 
[image]

Which is not the same as the book.

Comment: Would you prefer to read the original work of Hans Bethe where he talks about splitting? I had a soft copy of the English translation (the math in his work is well above my comfort zone) https://books.google.com/books?id=5baAG1WqgYQC&pg=PA1&dq=Term+splitting+in+crystals&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQodjQ_PbhAhUGD60KHVp7B58Q6AEIMTAC#v=onepage&q=Term%20splitting%20in%20crystals&f=false

Comment: There are two chapter in C. Ballhausen's book ' Introduction to Ligand Field Theory' that describe the calculation in great detail.  It was published some time ago but you may still be able to find a copy. The first step is however to convert the spherical harmonics into Cartesian x,x,z and impose octahedral or tetrahedral symmetry on the bare ion.

Comment: You might want to consider Figgis’s “Ligand Field Theory and it’s Applications”. I skipped the math, but it does a pretty good explanation for the definition of Dq, the AOM model etc.

Comment: Thank you all for your recommendations on book, now everything is much clearer. I still have problems so I will update (and erase parts of) the old question to the pertinent content at hand now.